# Clusweb7.vbs IIS CLUSTER

Tags: iis, cluster

I would like to ask if the Clusweb7.vbs script is mandatory on a IIS cluster created with 2 nodes Windows 2012. Basically I created the cluster and create the resource of my webapp and copied the script on C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\ of both nodes.
But it not clear to me what is the purpose of that script.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I think some more detail would be useful here if you want a quality answer.

Comment: If you read the original KB article from Microsoft, then you know whether that's mandatory, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/970759/configure-iis-world-wide-web-publishing-service-in-failover-cluster